# How can I talk to Neloth without him attacking me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

Every time I walk into the mushroom area, Neloth and his assistant try to kill me. I need to talk to them for the quest Path of Knowledge, but I'm not able to.

Comment: What quest? What people? There's a lot of important details missing here. We can't help you if we don't know what's going on.

Comment: Also, strongly suggest looking at the Skyrim wikis. There should be a page there related to whatever quest you're doing. Could really help a lot. http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_Wiki http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 2):

this may be because you have bounty in raven rock. trust me this has happen to me before on other missions so your best bet is to check your bounty in the main menu and then go to raven rock and either pay it off or get arrested. once you have done that try again and they should not attack you.

Answer (score 0):

When I was running around neloths assistants, one of the assistants had said, “for whiterun!” Made me think there. I knew I had a whiterun bounty so I went to clear it. When I came back everyone was chill. I know this is a late answer but for some future people. Check your whiterun bounty